# Making a model being able to convert itself to JSON

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I run through the JSON documentation at http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJsonRequests but didn't find what I needed. What I need is make my class being able to be converted to JSON like this:

```
# model
case class MyClass(a: Int, b: String ....)

# controller

def myAction = Action {
  val myClass = getMyClass()
  Ok(toJson(myClass))
}
```

So wherever I call `Ok(toJson(myClass))`, it converts to JSON by itself. How can I do this?

P.S. Sorry, I forgot to mention MyClass has `java.util.UUID` as an `Id` and some other class as a field:

```
case class MyClass(id: UUID, a: Int, b: String, c: MyClass2 ....)
```

So `Json.writes[MyClass]` doesn't work at least because of `UUID`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add a macro-generated `Writes[MyClass]` to companion object of `MyClass` like this:

```
object MyClass {
  implicit val myClassWrites = Json.writes[MyClass]
}
```

Method `toJson` implicitly accepts parameter of type `Writes[T]`. Compiler tries to find such implicit value and companion object of `MyClass` is always in scope when type parameter `T` is `MyClass`, so you don't have to import `myClassWrites` manually.

See also [Where does Scala look for implicits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits).

`Json.writes` requires implicit `Writes` for all constructor parameters.

```
case class MyClass(id: UUID, a: Int, b: String, c: MyClass2)
```

If `MyClass2` is a case class you should create `Writes[MyClass2]` using `Json.writes` in its companion object.

For `java.util.UUID` you should create `Writes` manually, for instance:

```
implicit val uuidWrites: Writes[UUID] = Writes{ uuid => JsString(uuid.toString) }
```

You could create `uuidWrites` in some helper object and than import when you need it like this:

```
object MyClass {
  import UuidHelper.uuidWrites 
  // note that you don't have to import MyClass2.myClass2Writes here
  implicit val myClassWrites = Json.writes[MyClass]
}
```

Comment: That's ok, I did it but take a look at my update please.

Comment: Try to provide separate Writes object for UUID object. Not sure if it work, though

Comment: since MyClass is a case class, won't creating object MyClass cause any error?

Comment: @Alex: Creation of a companion object for `case class` is a common practice. Compiler will **add** `apply` and `unapply` method to this companion object.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide an implicit val with `Writes[MyClass]` (or `Format`) description. 
Play2.0.x:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

implicit val myClassWrites = new Writes[MyClass] {
  def writes(c: MyClass): JsValue = {
    Json.obj(
        "a" -> c.a,
        "b" -> c.b,
         ...
    )
  }
}
```

Play2.1.x+

```
implicit val myClassWrites = (
  (__ \ "a").write[String] ~
  (__ \ "b").write[Int] ~
  ...
)(unlift(MyClass.unapply))
```

More docs: 
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJsonCombinators

But as `senia` mentioned, in a new versions of Play! you can use macro generators of Writes/Reads.
Docs: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJsonInception

```
implicit val myClassFormat = Json.format[MyClass]
```

This will provide you both Reads and Writes.

**Update:**
As you have updated your answer with additional class UUID, try to provide separate Writes or Format for UUID class. It won't work with macros, as it is from `java.util` package, so you should provide an custom Writes, like a mentioned before.